# Multiple iMessage and Facetime Activation Charges

Tags: facetime

I am from the Philippines and my carrier, Smart Communications billed me some PhP 810.81 (inclusive of 10% OC Tax) worth of text charges in my mobile phone statement of March 17, 2022.  I do not recognize this charge and I am disputing it as it is baseless and in fact, ridiculous.

Details of the charge showed a total of 81 SMS messages sent to an international number (+44 7786205094), all incurred in one, single day, on February 19, 2022.  The “Destination” was identified to be Apple iMessage & FaceTime Activation.

Smart Communications is charging PhP 9.09/unit of the SMS Activation request.  I am aware that an activation request triggers a verification from an Apple server abroad though the service is free from Apple’s side.

I contacted my provider to dispute and request a further review of the charges. My request was denied and was told I would have toggled the “Off/On” iMessage/ Facetime button if not intentionally then accidentally for which I would not have any reason to do so.

I would have hold myself responsible if I indeed used those services or make those changes, but not the case. Though hardly used, iMessage and FaceTime have been active on my phone for over three years now and never had issues with my bill before.  The services were “On” the whole time until I received this ridiculous charge which prompted me to switch the services “Off” on my phone indefinitely.

The charges started coming at 00:58 AM Philippine Time and every second thereafter until 2:42 AM.  I would have no reason to wake up that early just to toggle the switch multiple times. Another batch of charges came again between 5:54 PM and 10:21 PM.  To interpret the bill, the service would have been turned off 40 times and turned on 41 times in 5 hours time in a single day.  I am not an Olympian who would have the tenacity and energy to toggle the switch off/on and at the rate of 3.8 times per minute for no reason.  If not absurd I don’t even think this is humanly and technically possible.  I'm just wondering if there's any creature on earth who would have any reason to do such ridiculous thing.

More so I am also aware of the fact that turnaround time for iMessage/Facetime activation is at least 24 hours. Thus it would take another day to activate the service once turned off and there is no way for it to have been turned off/on 81 times in less than a day.

I did not change SIM card nor Apple ID, iOS is latest version, all settings perfect including timezone. Who's at fault here?  Apple or Smart Philippines who issued the most stupid bill on earth.

Comment: I don't know who's at fault, but Smart appears listed as a supported wireless carrier (see https://support.apple.com/HT203982), and, according to https://support.apple.com/HT201422 (scroll to section "Still not activated after a day?") you don't need to send or receive international SMS messages for supported wireless carriers when activating iMessage and Facetime, so you may want to contact Smart/Apple and ask why those 81 activation SMS messages were sent to an international number instead of a local number in the first place.

Comment: That’s the same issue I have now with Smart. I was charged 21 SMS in 3 seconds. I am still disputing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Walking who is at fault is highly opinionated. Would you consider editing in a [more subjective question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404573/) if you have one. Also please consider that [customer support type questions can be voted closed as off topic as well](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2508/5472)